# Pagina en blanco al generar pdf con dompdf, no muestra mensaje de error

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

necesito de su ayuda, en local especificamente en xamp tengo un proyecto donde estoy generando un pdf, en un archivo tengo la consulta pdf y los parametros de dompdf, y en otro archivo tengo es las tablas,lo que me visualizo en pdf, en local me va todo bien, pero a la hora de subirlo al servidor, al ejecutar para generar el pdf solo me carga la pagina en blanco total, no me aparece ni un mensaje ni un error nada. porfavor si me podrian ayudar. abajo dejo los codigos que tengo.

```
<?php    
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['active']))
{
header('location: ../');
}
include "../../conexion.php";
require_once '../pdf/vendor/autoload.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
ob_start(); //se carga en memoria o en buffer el archivo y se pueden usar las variables globalmente
if(empty($_REQUEST['cl']) || empty($_REQUEST['f']))
{
echo "No es posible generar la factura.";
}else{
$codCliente = $_REQUEST['cl'];
$noFactura = $_REQUEST['f'];
$anulada = '';
$query_config   = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tbl_configuracion");
$result_config  = mysqli_num_rows($query_config);
if($result_config > 0){
$configuracion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_config);
}
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT f.Id_pedidos, DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha_pedidos, '%d/%m/%Y') as fecha, DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha_pedidos,'%H:%i:%s') as  hora, f.Idcliente_pedidos, f.estatus_pedidos, v.nombre_empleados as vendedor, v.apellido_empleados as apevendedor,cl.Id_clientes, cl.ci_clientes, cl.nombre_clientes, cl.apellido_clientes,cl.telefono_clientes, cl.direccion_clientes
FROM tbl_pedidos f INNER JOIN tbl_empleados v ON f.Idempleados_pedidos = v.Id_empleados
INNER JOIN tbl_clienteS cl ON f.Idcliente_pedidos = cl.Id_clientes WHERE f.Id_pedidos = $noFactura AND f.Idcliente_pedidos = $codCliente AND f.estatus_pedidos != 10 ");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($result > 0){
$factura = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$no_factura = $factura['Id_pedidos'];
if($factura['estatus_pedidos'] == 2){
$anulada = '<img class="anulada" src="sistema/factura/img/anulado.png" alt="Anulada">';
}if ($factura['estatus_pedidos'] == 3){
$anulada ='<img class="entregado" src="img/entregado2.png" alt="Entregado">';
}
$query_productos = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT p.descripcion_producto,dt.cantidad_detallepedidos,dt.precioventa_detalle,(dt.cantidad_detallepedidos * dt.precioventa_detalle) as precio_total
FROM tbl_pedidos f
INNER JOIN tbl_detallepedidos dt
ON f.Id_pedidos = dt.npedido_detallepedido
INNER JOIN tbl_productos p
ON dt.codpro_detallepedidos = p.Id_producto
WHERE f.Id_pedidos = $no_factura ");
$result_detalle = mysqli_num_rows($query_productos);
include(dirname('__FILE__').'/factura.php'); //ACCEDE A LA DIRECCION DEL ARCHIVO, SE CARGA EN LA MEMORIA CON EL OB_START
$html = ob_get_clean();
// USO DE LA LIBRERIA
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'Courier');
$dompdf->loadHtml(utf8_decode($html)); //CARGA EL CONTENIDO QUE SE VA A MOSTRAR
// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('letter', 'portrait'); //ESPECIFICA EL TAMAﾃ前 DEL PAPEL Y ORIENTACION
// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();//LEE EL HTML PARA TRASLADAR A PDF
// Output the generated PDF to Browser
ob_get_clean();
$dompdf->stream('factura_'.$noFactura.'.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0)); //SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
exit;
}
}
?>
```

Documento donde muestro la tabla con los datos extraidos:

```
<?php
$subtotal   = 0;
$iva        = 0;
$impuesto   = 0;
$tl_sniva   = 0;
$total      = 0;
 //print_r($configuracion); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pedido</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $anulada; ?>
<div id="page_pdf">
<table id="factura_head">
<tr>
<td class="logo_factura">
<div>
<img src="sistema/img/logo1.jpg">
</div>
</td>
<td class="info_empresa">
<?php
if($result_config > 0){
$iva = $configuracion['iva_configuracion'];
?>
<div>
<span class="h2"><?php echo strtoupper($configuracion['nombre_configuracion']); ?></span>
<p><?php echo $configuracion['razonsocial_configuracion']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $configuracion['direccion_configuracion']; ?></p>
<p>NIT: <?php echo $configuracion['ruc_configuracion']; ?></p>
<p>Teléfono: <?php echo $configuracion['telefono_configuracion']; ?></p>
<p>Email: <?php echo $configuracion['email_configuracion']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

</td>

<td class="info_factura">
<div class="round">
<span class="h3">Pedido</span>
<p>No. Pedido: <strong><?php echo $factura['Id_pedidos']; ?></strong></p>
<p>Fecha: <?php echo $factura['fecha']; ?></p>
<p>Hora: <?php echo $factura['hora']; ?></p>
<p>Vendedor: <?php echo $factura['vendedor']; ?> <?php echo utf8_decode($factura['apevendedor']); ?></p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="factura_cliente">
<tr>
<td class="info_cliente">
<div class="round">
<span class="h3">Cliente</span>
<table class="datos_cliente">
<tr>
<td><label>Cédula:</label><p><?php echo $factura['ci_clientes']; ?></p></td>
<td><label>Teléfono:</label> <p><?php echo $factura['telefono_clientes']; ?></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Nombre:</label> <p><?php echo utf8_decode($factura['nombre_clientes']); ?> <?php echo utf8_decode($factura['apellido_clientes']); ?></p></td>
<td><label>Dirección:</label> <p><?php echo $factura['direccion_clientes']; ?></p></td>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="factura_detalle">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="50px">Cant.</th>
<th class="textleft">Descripción</th>
<th class="textright" width="150px">Precio Unitario.</th>
<th class="textright" width="150px"> Precio Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detalle_productos">
<?php
if($result_detalle > 0){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_productos)){
?>
<tr>
<td class="textcenter"><?php echo $row['cantidad_detallepedidos']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['descripcion_producto']; ?></td>
<td class="textright"><?php echo $row['precioventa_detalle']; ?></td>
<td class="textright"><?php echo $row['precio_total']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$precio_total = $row['precio_total'];
$subtotal = round($subtotal + $precio_total, 2);
}
}
$impuesto   = round($subtotal * ($iva / 100), 2);
$tl_sniva   = round($subtotal - $impuesto,2 );
$total      = round($tl_sniva + $impuesto,2);
?>
</tbody>
<tfoot id="detalle_totales">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="textright"><span>SUBTOTAL $</span></td>
<td class="textright"><span><?php echo $tl_sniva; ?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="textright"><span>IVA (<?php echo $iva; ?> %)</span></td>
<td class="textright"><span><?php echo $impuesto; ?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="textright"><span>TOTAL $</span></td>
<td class="textright"><span><?php echo $total; ?></span></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
<div>
<h4 class="label_gracias">¡Gracias por su Pedido!</h4>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

funcion donde genero el pdf:

```
function generarPDF(cliente,factura){
// Variables define el alto de la ventana para mostrar
var ancho = 1000;
var alto = 800;
// Calcular posocion x,y para centrar la ventana
var x = parseInt((window.screen.width/2) - (ancho / 2));
var y = parseInt((window.screen.height/2) - (alto / 2));
$url = 'factura/generaFactura.php?cl='+cliente+'&f='+factura;
// Posciones
window.open($url,"Factura","left="+x+",top="+y+",height="+alto+",width="+ancho+",scrollbar=si,location=no,resizable=si,menubar=no");
}
```

el problema es que al generar el pdf aparece la ventana en blanco, no carga los datos de la consulta, no crea la estructura de la tabla que ya tengo hecha.la version de php es 7.2 y de dompdf es 1.1.1. porfavor quien me pudda ayduar.

Comment: Un consejo: cuesta un rato entender todo ese código porque carece de **indentación**. Por favor, evita eso porque provocas que su lectura sea más dificil y perdamos la motivación para poderte ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Usa esto en el PHP que te de problemas:(si es posible nada mas abrir el tag de php) ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: muchas gracias @DavidGonzalo, efectivamente me ayudó a darme cuenta de un error que no aparecía al cargar el pdf.

Comment: logré dar con la solución, debía de actualizar la librería y poner las variables de dompdf correctamente, que en el readme estaban.